# PROC SQL Numeric value 'NULL' is not recognized

Tags: null, numeric, proc-sql

I am trying to use case when statement to compare 2 columns with number and 'Null' value, the Proc SQL will return error as Numeric value 'NULL' is not recognized.

How to fix my code? Data type for Column A and B is VARCHAR(10).

```
Table alpha has 2 columns as 
column A include 1,2,3,Null,4
column B include 3,2,1,4,Null
```

```
SELECT  case when  A = B
        then 'YES' 
        else 'NO' end 
FROM alpha
```

I tried to use coalesce(B,2) to assign a number for Null value, but returned same error

```
error as Numeric value 'NULL' is not recognized.
```

However, I can use following code to find Null Row in Column a or b

```
select * from alpha 
where b = 'NULL'
```

Comment: what kind of sql engine is it?

Comment: PROC SQL is the engine

Comment: OK I don't know it but I think you should look into how to cast those NULL values into numerics, or filter them out before they get to the = function.

Comment: It looks like you did not put NULL value into the table but "NULL" as a string. Can you verify this being the case?

Answer (score 0):

Check the table to make sure that the 'Null' value is actually NULL.
Then use the 'IS NULL' statement to check b.

```
select * from alpha 
where b is null
```